# Finding Matches Tindr style - pairing 2 Users together that can Approve or Deny the match

Tags: postgresql, activerecord

I am building a dating site matching `Users` to each other via an `Approval` model, filtered by a `ranking` value.

1 `Approval` can be created for any pair of `Users`. The code below works, initially, but it has a serious flaw: It only finds the first `N` possible matches, where `N` is 20 in the first line of `User#potential_matches` method.

From this list of potential matches I exclude any `Approvals` that have already been `matched` or `denied_at`.

I'm looking for an efficient way to find matches for `Users`.

I could start at User id 1 and iterate -- but this is terribly inefficient.

Ideally, I'd like to filter the `Approval` models based on the `User.id` -- if there's an `Approval` with a `user_id` of 10 and a non-nil `user1_approval` value, it shouldn't be shown to User ID 10. It *will* be shown for the User with the `approved_id`.

The difference between `user_id` & `approved_id` is just to pair with 2 different Users. They are sorted by name before created in `Approval.user_approval` .

How can I efficiently pair my `Users` together with the `Approval` model?

```
class Approval < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :approved, class_name: "User"

    def self.user_approval(user1, user2)
        sorted = [user1, user2].sort_by { |u| u.name}
        Approval.find_or_create_by(user: sorted[0], approved: sorted[1])
    end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "approvals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "approved_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "user1_approval"
    t.datetime "user2_approval"
    t.datetime "denied_at"
    t.boolean  "approved"
    t.boolean  "matched"
  end


User.rb:

  def self.potential_matches(user)
    users = user.where('ranking >= ? AND ranking <= ? AND id != ?', user.lowest_eligible_ranking ,
                                                   user.maximum_eligible_ranking,
                                                   user.id).limit(20)
    approvals = []
    users.each do |s|
      approvals.push(Approval.user_approval(user, s))
    end

    approvals.reject! { |a| a.denied_at != nil}
    approvals.reject! { |a| a.matched == true}

    approvals
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to scrap the `Approval` model and use a `Decision` model instead - one per "vote" of approving or rejecting.

It made the lookups much easier.

Answer (score 0):

pardon the obvious but does removing the limit do anything?

```
users = user.where('ranking >= ? AND ranking <= ? AND id != ?', user.lowest_eligible_ranking, user.maximum_eligible_ranking, user.id).limit(20)
```

to

```
users = user.where('ranking >= ? AND ranking <= ? AND id != ?', user.lowest_eligible_ranking, user.maximum_eligible_ranking, user.id)
```